# Why h2 and mysql database locations are different in eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, h2

This is a stupid question and I know it, nevertheless I'd like to understand how these two databases are handled within my system.

I have eclipse IDE with two projects: `h2_test` and `mysql_test`, where `h2_test` is configured to use h2 database and `mysql_test` is configured to use mysql database.

In `h2_test` I have h2 location configured as `String url = "jdbc:h2:~/h2_db"` whereas in `mysql_test` as `<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>`. As you might have guessed `h2_test` is a normal java project and `mysql_test` is dynamic web project.

When I run my `h2_db` my h2 database instance is created on my hard drive at ~/ directory.
When I run my `msql_db` my mysql database instance is created in memory?

I must add that to actually run mysql I had to install it and run as a system.service while for h2 all I had to do is to connect a h2 driver in eclipse. Why so much hassle with mysql?

1. Why I can't use the same logic with mysql db and create is as `jdbc:mysql:~/mysql_db`?
2. How are these set-ups different and which one is preferable for a web application?

Comment: MySQL is also stored in hard disk like h2. But the way it handles the files is way different than the toy database h2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

h2 DB is a standalone database, that a single Java application loads directly and operates on. Usually, a single application can use a DB at a time. Other DBs of this sort are the key-value LevelDB and Java's DB4O.

MySQL, on the other hand, is designed to be more powerful, in that it is run in a server process (written in C++). Applications (a large number simultaneously) can connect to a given MySQL server (with authentication), even from different hosts.

Comment: Does it mean that mysql is better for a simple web app than h2?

Comment: @minerals Yes, even if only due to scalability.

Comment: @minerals h2 is for testing purposes. If you want to go for a real world application, at least use MySQL, which can become a toy after heavy processes in your application.